# Prove without writing all cases that there are more odd numbers from 1 to 199 than even numbers from 1 to 199

Tags: combinatorics

Prove without writing all cases that there are more odd numbers from 1 to 199 than even numbers from 1 to 199

How do we do this in the general case from an arbitrary starting point which was 1 in this case and ending point (199 in this case)?

Comment: The first and last number in the sequence are both odd.

Comment: Peter Foreman had the clearest answer and I think you should have chosen his instead of that of callculus. If there are equal numbers of odd/even between $1$ and $200$, there is $1$ less even between $1$ and $199$. If that isn't good enough, consider the first comment where the first and last number are odd. This is your generality. If first and last are of opposite parity, the number of odd/even is equal. If they are of the same parity, then $that$ parity is greater than the other.

Comment: I like the algorithmic approach better

Comment: @poetasis Your comment doesn´t make sense to me. You say that the answer of Peter Forman is the clearest answer and then you go on try to give an explanation which is somehow similar to mine.

Comment: @callculus I was defending another answer as being clearer at first glance. First, you reversed $m,n$ . Should be $m$ is last, $n$ is first. Your answer was correct (except for the reversal) but required study.

Comment: @poetasis It was a uselful hint that I mixed up $m$ and $n$. Thanks. So it was useful that we both write our comments.

Comment: @callculus I removed the downvote. Thank you for your modesty.

Comment: @poetasis Thanks for removing the $\downarrow$. Sometimes the most obvious flaws are  flaws which are the hardest to discover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let´s say the starting number is $m$ and the last number is $n$. Then you evaluate if $n-m+1$ is divisible by 2. If this is the case then the number of odd numbers equals the number of even numbers.

If $m-n+1$ is not divisible by 2 then we have

a) more odd numbers than even numbers if $m$ is an odd number.

b) more even numbers than odd numbers if $m$ is an even number.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
There are $100$ even and $100$ odd numbers from $1$ to $200$.

Comment: I can't use this rule for starting at 53 and ending at 796. What's a more general observation that let's me solve it for starting at n and ending at m?

Comment: There are $\frac{796-52}{2}$ even/odd numbers in that range.

Comment: If that number $\frac{m-n}{2}$ is even, what does it mean? Else, what if that number is odd?

Comment: Both examples you have given start at an odd number $n$ and end at an even number $m$. When this occurs there are $\frac{m-n+1}2$ even/odd numbers (consider from $1$ to $m-n+1$ instead). For any other case, remove the initial/ending values until it is of this form, then add them to the corresponding totals.

Answer (score 0):

Two adjacent natural numbers will be of different parity.

$\{\color{red}{1,2},\color{blue}{3,4},\color{green}{5,6},\dots\}$

It follows that if there are an even number of consecutive numbers then there are the same number of numbers of each parity type.

Otherwise, it follows that if there are an odd number of consecutive numbers then there is one more number of numbers of the type of the final appearing number.

Answer (score 0):

Define functions $O$ and $E$ on the positive integers as follows:
$O(n)$ is the number of odd integers in the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$
and $E(n)$ is the number of even integers in the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}.$

You can show by induction that $O(n)=E(n)$ if $n$ is even and $O(n)=E(n)+1$ if $n$ is odd.

Then the number of odd integers in the range from $m$ to $n$ inclusive (that is, in the set $\{m,m+1,\ldots,n\}$)
is $O(n)-O(m-1)$
and the number of even integers in the same range is $E(n)-E(m-1).$
The number of odd integers in that range is greater than, equal to, or less than the number of even integers when the difference
$$
(O(n)-O(m-1))-(E(n)-E(m-1)) = (O(n)-E(n))-(O(m-1)-E(m-1))
$$
is greater than, equal to, or less than  zero, respectively.
Now use the fact that $O(k)-E(k)$ is $1$ if $k$ is odd and $0$ if $k$ is even.